# Finding radical of $l^1(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: banach-algebras

Find the radical of $l^1(\mathbb Z)$
Now we know that radical of a Banach algebra is the intersection of kernels of all $\phi$ where $\phi$ is a nonzero complex homomorphism. But how do I find complex homomorphism on $l^1(\mathbb Z)$?